# Webstorm: save individual tabs instead of save all?

Tags: webstorm

**UPDATE**: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282265/webstorm-save-only-open-tab-vs-save-all-tabs, please direct answers there.

---

I'm new to webstorm since I started my latest job, and I'm finding some features difficult to adapt to. In particular, the fact that it forces you to save all open changes in all tabs at once is problematic.

I have a somewhat organic method of development, swapping between HTML and LESS frequently until I reach a point where I want to save the files and see what my work has accomplished. Whenever I save an open HTML doc, it saves the incomplete LESS that I just left mid-thought as well, and pops up a compiler error. Is there any way to force webstorm to only save the active tab?

(Aside: Please don't suggest I adjust my mindset or my workflow to adapt to my environment. Not only is that poor usability, it would require me to override an instinct that was developed for good reason: when you reach a milestone, you save it lest something bad happen. Leaving an unsaved doc open makes my eye twitch.)

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282265/webstorm-save-only-open-tab-vs-save-all-tabs

Comment: Indeed - I realized after a posted that it might be more pertinent to post on SO, since its implications are purely code-based. Feel free to close this one if it's problematic.